# Type cast InputStream to ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android

I have written a byte[][][][] object to a file using this code:

```
byte[][][][] allMaps = new byte[10][8][][];
allMaps = ...;
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
  try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("all_maps"));
        outputStream.writeObject(allMaps);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       ...
      }
```

Now I'm trying to read that byte[][][][] object into my Android app:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("raw/all_maps", "raw", getPackageName()) );
    try {
        byteMaps = (byte[][][][]) ((ObjectInputStream) inputStream).readObject();
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        ...
```

But then I get this error (in the line starting with "byteMaps"):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectInputStream
```

Why is `inputStream` of the type `AssetInputStream` and not `java.io.InputStream`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually don't type cast streams but wrap (decorate) them with a proper Input/Output stream class to read the content of the stream in an easier way. Here, you have to replace this:

```
byteMaps = (byte[][][][]) ((ObjectInputStream) inputStream).readObject();
```

into:

```
ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
try {
    byteMaps = (byte[][][][]) oos.readObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create object of ObjectInputStream with 'inputStream'.. Pass inputStream as an arguments to the constructor of ObjectInputStream. Then call readObject() on objectInputStream object.. Hope it helps.

---